# How to find all envelopes where specified signer or recipient exists

Tags: docusignapi

I want to find all envelopes (documents) which were signed by a user via API. I know the email of the user.

I checked https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/search and https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges.

But non of them solving my issue because they return all envelopes, and there is no way to return only envelopes after filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the v2.1 of the API for this.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search

You need to use the query string parameter `search_text` and add the email in there to filter by recipients.